# CSS transition not running after element is moved to different parent

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I got two list of elements and I want to move items from one list to another with a simple CSS transition.

The logic:

- Add the `hidden` class to element in order to fade it out (`opacity: 0, width: 0, plus transition`)
- When the transition ends move the element to another list
- Remove `hidden` class so the element will fade-in

---

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="item2">Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
    <li id="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="item4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
...
li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    width: 80px;
}

li.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
}
...
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        var $item = $(this),
            parentId = $item.parent().attr('id'),
            newParentSelector = (parentId == 'list1') ? '#list2' : '#list1';


        $item.addClass('hidden');

        $item.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
            $item.appendTo(newParentSelector);
            $item.removeClass('hidden');
        });

    });
});
```

---

When on the `LI` item the `.hidden` class is added the transition animation runs as expected. When the LI item is moved to another list and the .hidden class is removed the transition animation is not running but the item appears with correct opacity and width.

The weirder thing is that when I toggle the 'hidden' class of an item manually (i.e `$('#item2').toggleClass('hidden');` ) both `fade-in` and `fade-out`animations run.

The problem is demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HwHP/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain to you **why** this works, but setting a timeout (even if it is 1ms) seems to make it work.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/2HwHP/1/).

**Relevant code**

```
$item.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
    $item.appendTo(newParentSelector);
    setTimeout(function() {
           $item.removeClass('hidden');
    }, 1);
});
```

---

EDIT 1:
After testing it seems that Chrome and FF deal with this as we expect but IE10 doesn't want to. Setting a timeout of around 50 should do the trick.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/2HwHP/2/).

```
$item.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
    $item.appendTo(newParentSelector);
    setTimeout(function() {
            $item.removeClass('hidden');
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Weird but it worked.
The reason 1 millisecond doesn't work on IE is because different browsers have different ticks for the timer (IE rounds 1 to 0 while others round 1 to the next acceptable value). It's usually best to put at least 20ms delay.